# async / await and Fiddler Demo

Tags: c#, async-await

**Right to the Point**

Why is it if I try running the code below in Visual Studio, and have a break point on the “**string urlContents = await getStringTask;**” line, I don’t see the call to msdn.microsoft.com until after I execute that line.

I would expect the call to msdn.microsoft.com  to occur after processing executes line: **Task getStringTask = client.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com");**

That's the point of an async method, correct? To kick off tasks that might take a while to run (client.GetStringAsync) so independent work (DoIndependentWork();) can continue while the longer task do their thing.

I am confused by my results.  Can someone explain why this occurred.

I am thinking it is because I am running everything on my development machine.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        // Mark the event handler with async so you can use await in it.
        private async void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            int contentLength = await AccessTheWebAsync();

            resultsTextBox.Text +=
                String.Format("\r\nLength of the downloaded string: {0}.\r\n", contentLength);
        }


        // Three things to note in the signature:
        //  - The method has an async modifier. 
        //  - The return type is Task or Task<T>. (See "Return Types" section.)
        //    Here, it is Task<int> because the return statement returns an integer.
        //  - The method name ends in "Async."
        async Task<int> AccessTheWebAsync()
        {
            // You need to add a reference to System.Net.Http to declare client.
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            // GetStringAsync returns a Task<string>. That means that when you await the
            // task you'll get a string (urlContents).
            Task<string> getStringTask = client.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com");

            // You can do work here that doesn't rely on the string from GetStringAsync.
            DoIndependentWork();

            // The await operator suspends AccessTheWebAsync.
            //  - AccessTheWebAsync can't continue until getStringTask is complete.
            //  - Meanwhile, control returns to the caller of AccessTheWebAsync.
            //  - Control resumes here when getStringTask is complete. 
            //  - The await operator then retrieves the string result from getStringTask.
            string urlContents = await getStringTask;

            // The return statement specifies an integer result.
            // Any methods that are awaiting AccessTheWebAsync retrieve the length value.
            return urlContents.Length;
        }

        void DoIndependentWork()
        {
            resultsTextBox.Text += "Working . . . . . . .\r\n";
        }
```

**More History and Why are I am asking the questions above**

My boss and I were discussing the async / await commands after I read: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443(vs.110).aspx (which is where I got the code from above.)  There was some debate over how the commands worked so my boss asked me to do some investigation.  He suggested running the code above and monitoring it against Fiddler.  When I did that I didn’t get the result I expected.  I would have expected the call to msdn.microsoft.com to occur after line (Task getStringTask = client.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com");).  However, it didn't occur

So, I continued to do research on the commands.  Which prompted me to create another demo.  I set up the new demo like the one above. However, this demo made a call to a database using an async method, then did some independent work (just like above) and then used the await command (just like above).  I monitored this demo using SQL Profiler.  This demo gave me the results I would have expected.  It proved to me that the async command kicks of the database call before it ran the IndependentWork method.

Here is the code just in case I didn’t explain it clearly

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public Task<string> Index()
    {
        var returnValue = MacroService();

        return returnValue;
    }

    public async Task<string> MacroService()
    {
        Task<string> getStringTask = MicroDataService("MicroDataServiceCall");

        string string2 = IndependentWork("IndependentWorkCall");

        string stringTask1 = await getStringTask;

        return $"{stringTask1}, {string2}";
    }

    public async Task<string> MicroDataService(string parm)
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xzz"].ConnectionString;

        var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        var command = new SqlCommand("sproc", conn);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        param.Value = "00000";
        command.Parameters.Add(param);

        conn.Open();
        await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        conn.Close();

        return parm;
    }

    public string IndependentWork(string parm)
    {
        return parm;
    }
```

So, I want to understand why I don’t get the same result from the original demo since I know my boss is going to ask.

I am thinking it is because I am running everything on my development machine for the first demo.  In the second demo, I am actually using a database server so the second demo kicks off the database processing on that machine.

Let me know.  Thanks!!!

Sorry if my description / expectation is not clear. Let me try to be clearer.

My expected result for the first demo was that I would see a call in Fiddler to http://msdn.microsoft.com after Task getStringTask = client.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com"); executed. However, I did not see a call in Fiddler until after line string urlContents = await getStringTask; executed.

Therefore, the first demo did not give me the result I expected.

However, the second demo gave me the results I expected.  Which was that I saw a call to the database in SQL Profiler after line: Task getStringTask = MicroDataService("MicroDataServiceCall"); executed.

So, I am trying to understand why I got different behavior. I would have thought that demo1 would have kicked off the async method. I would have seen an entry in Fiddler. Processing would continue in the IndependentWork method.  Then continue after the result were returned from the async call.  This is what is happening in the second demo.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the behavior you observe is because the debugger stops execution of the application before the request is made.

When you hit a breakpoint in a debugger, the whole application stops, it doesn't stop just the current thread. And if the `async` method you called did not make the request before it returned the `Task`, then you will not see it in Fiddler.

This probably also explains why you don't observe this with other methods: they do manage to make the request before returning.